# How to limit post content and remove image caption from it

Tags: content, the-content, captions

I am using this function to limit the content in my themes. But the problem is whenever I call the function, it also displays the image caption. I want to remove the image caption when calling the_content_limit function.

Here is the code:

```
function the_content_limit($max_char, $more_link_text = '', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {

    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);

    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

    $content = strip_tags($content);



   if (strlen($_GET['p']) > 0) {

      echo "";

      echo $content;

      echo "&nbsp;<a href='";

      the_permalink();

      echo "'>"."Read More &rarr;</a>";

      echo "";

   }

   else if ((strlen($content)>$max_char) && ($espacio = strpos($content, " ", $max_char ))) {

        $content = substr($content, 0, $espacio);

        $content = $content;

        echo "";

        echo $content;

        echo "...";

        echo "&nbsp;<a href='";

        the_permalink();

        echo "'>"."</a>";

        echo "";

   }

   else {

      echo "";

      echo $content;

      echo "&nbsp;<a href='";

      the_permalink();

      echo "'>"."Read More &rarr;</a>";

      echo "";

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image captions in Wordpress are actually shortcodes.
Shortcodes are applied by the filter:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

For example, Wordpress creates the following code in your content when you enter an image caption:

```
[caption id="attachment_55" align="alignleft" width="127" caption="Here is my caption"][/caption]
```

You need to still use apply_filters() in order to [properly display content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage). (safe content display and all other shortcodes)

If you don't want shortcodes (which is what it looks like, since you are doing a striptags) you should just use this:

```
 $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
```

But if it is specifically [caption] shortcodes, I assume this could work, if you just want to add a string-replace line to your code:

```
$content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
// remove [caption] shortcode
$content = preg_replace("/\[caption.*\[\/caption\]/", '', $content);
// short codes are applied
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. That's all I wanted to do.