# Prevent WP from wrapping html in caption shortcode after 'image_send_editor' filter is applied

Tags: images, filters, shortcode, post-editor

In my `functions.php` I have cooked up some functions to filter the attachment output code, when an attachment is sent to the editor.

```
function filter_image_send_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) { 
  $arr = get_attachments_and_widths_arr($id);
  return attachments_and_widths_to_html($arr, $id, $align, $caption, $alt);
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'filter_image_send_to_editor', 10, 9);
```

The return statement returns a **string** that contains **pure html** code and already has the caption text properly added to it. The problem is that because the `Media Libary` has some text in the 'Caption' field for that image and it automatically *adds the `[caption]` shortcode around my html code after the above function returns*. So I guess `strip_shortcode()` will not work in my case, since the string I am returning as filtered code does not yet have any shortcode, `[caption`] is added after the function returns.

How do I prevent this from happening?

EDIT: I know about [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70761/how-to-limit-post-content-and-remove-image-caption-from-it), but I would like WP not to send any shortcode to the editor at all. The solution in that post removes the [caption] code when the post html is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the disable_captions filter, Just put it in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'disable_captions', create_function('$a', 'return true;') );
```

Edit: As toscho pointed out this is a better solution!

`add_filter( 'disable_captions', '__return_true' );`